# Connect to MySQL Server inside Docker container in an Microsoft Azure VM

Tags: mysql, azure, docker

I created an Ubuntu 15.10 VM on Microsoft Azure.
On the Server i created a docker container with MySQL running (IP: 172.17.0.2)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4255233555db        mysql               "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   compose_mysql_1
```

I can connect over ssh to the VM and then access the MySQL-Server running in the docker container.

I now wanna have access to the MySQL-Server from the outside so that my WebApp on Microsoft Azure (same Ressource Group) can connect to the database.

I already forwarded the port 3306 of the VM to 172.17.0.2:3306.

With MySQL-Workbench from my local PC i can't connect to the MySQL-Server.
In fact i am not sure which credentials i need to provide to connect.
I tried it with the public ip of the VM and the root password of the MySQL-Server. But shouldn't i somewhere also provide the password and user for the VM itself?

Comment: how did you forward the port in azure? I'm having this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the firewall on the actual VM, Azure manage ports security using a separate VPC Network security group. By default, the Network group associated with your VM does not allow inbound TCP connections on port 3306. You have to add that manually:

1. Go to `Network interfaces`

[image: Pic 1]

2. Select your network interface

[image]

3. Select `Network security group`

[image]

4. Select your group (usually only one here)

[image]

5. Select `Inbound security rules`

[image]

6. Click `Add` and Fill as follow

[image]

7. Finally apply the changes and wait for 1-2 minutes (time for the new settings to propagate correctly, although it should be instantly)

[image]

Magic!

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative to directly using official MySQL images

I also had troubles getting the official MySQL image running and accessible. [sameersbn/docker-mysql](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql) provides an nice and easy wrapper that lets you specify user and database to be set up.

My docker-compose file has the following section:

```
db:
  image: sameersbn/mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
    - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
    - DB_NAME=theDatabaseName
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

The details:

- `image` - The above mentioned wrapper.
- `volumes` - Mapping the data on the persistent host.
- `environment` - Variables that define the database setup. Either give plain text as with `DB_NAME` or access environment variables through the `${...}` syntax.
- `ports` - Map out the port 3306 on the host so it may be accessed remotely.